# Can the iteration code be reduced through a for loop?

Tags: python

```
self.button1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(self.button1))
self.button2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(self.button1))
self.button3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(self.button1))
self.button4.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(self.button1))
self.button5.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(self.button1))
```

how to summarise this code in for loop like this

```
for i in range(1, 10):
exec("%s.%s(%s)" %(f"self.button{i}", "clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker", f"self.button{i})"),)
```

error :: class name error self is not defined

how can i fix it
or another way to summarize iteration code

Comment: Put all the buttons in a list and iterate over them that way.

Comment: Would you not want `self.clicker(self.button2)` etc?

Answer (score 2):

You can do with `getattr`,

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    getattr(self, f'button{i}').clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(self.button1))
```

`getattr(self, f'button{i}')` give you the attributes of `self` such as `button1, button2.. etc`

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `getattr`:

```py
for button in [self.button1, self.button2, self.button3, self.button4, self.button5]:
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(self.button1))
```

Or if the repeated `button1` is a typo:

```py
for button in [self.button1, self.button2, self.button3, self.button4, self.button5]:
    button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(button))
```

Or you might want to store your buttons in a container, a `dict`, say:

```py
class Blahaj:
    def __init__(self):
        self._buttons = {}
        self._buttons[1] = Button(...)
        self._buttons[2] = Button(...)
        self._buttons[3] = Button(...)
        self._buttons[4] = Button(...)
        self._buttons[5] = Button(...)

        for button in self._buttons.values():
            button.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(button))
```

Answer (score 0):

`exec` function has 3 arguments,

```py
exec(source, globals=None, locals=None)
```

you can set in locals a dictionary with the locals variables to use in the source code, in this case, you need to pass the variable self (that carry the reference of the class where you are executing the exec function)

```py
exec(f"self.button{i}.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicker(self.button1)", None, {"self": self})
```